# javascript form error

Tags: javascript

I have my HTML structure in the following format

```
<div>
<form class="form-inline" style="padding-top:10px" action="javascript:function()">   <!-- a search bar-->
  <input id="id" type="text" " placeholder="Something">
   </form>

<button onClick="somefunction()"> b</button>
</div>
```

the problem is I want the search bar to work when I press enter in it but unfortunately it is submitting the button element ,  I am slightly confused as the button is not a form element and I have specifically defined onClick. I am new to javascript so I am sure it is something small but I have not been able to solve it.

ie when I press enter , the  "somefunction()" gets active as opposed to "function()"

Comment: What do you mean "it is submitting the button element?"

Comment: why is the form action value a"javascript:function()"?

Comment: There is also a rouge " inbetween type="text" " placeholder="Something" in the unclosed input tag

Answer (score 0):

You may put your button inside the form and have the function called in `onClick` return false, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/634150).

**EDIT**

According to your edit and your comments on what you want, you may do the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function formfunction(){
            alert("form function is called.");
        }
        function somefunction(){
            alert("the button is clicked.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form name="myform" action="#" onsubmit="formfunction(); return false;">
    <input id="id" type="text" placeholder="Something">
</form>
<button type="button" onClick="somefunction()"> b</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't get what you wanted. I've edited my answer, see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <form class="form-inline" style="padding-top:10px" action="someFile.php" onsubmit="return someFunc();"> 
        <input id="id" type="text" placeholder="Something">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JS**

```
function someFunc(){
    // code goes here
    return false;
}
```

[**Just an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ucy/).

Comment: Thank you , but the button condition just popped up again  ! Did not work

Comment: Well, I think you want to execute `sumeFunc` on button press and this answer is all about that. Did you check the example ?

Comment: I did , but maybe I am still a little confused , on the button click I want another  function to be executed and on return I want the function linked with the form element to be executed